# Directshow render onto panel using c++ Builder

Tags: video, c++builder, directshow

I am trying to get a directshow player to display on a panel other than the main window in c++ builder.  I took the Microsoft sample player code and made this into a c++ application which created the form and played the video onto the window.

I a now want to add to a vcl application and want to display the video onto a specific panel.  Anytime I try to run the graph under VCL it will only build and run if I pass handle as the application handle rather than a panel handle.  I know the graph runs because i hear the audio, but i cannot get the video to render to a panel.  If i pass hwnd as Handle of any VCL window  the callback assignment fails for the filtergraph (SetNotifyWindow), it works if I pass Application->Handle.

```
    hr = m_pEvent->SetNotifyWindow((OAHWND)m_hwnd, WM_GRAPH_EVENT, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }
```

The Video render function ties to find best suited renderer as follows

```cpp
HRESULT DShowPlayer::CreateVideoRenderer()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    enum { Try_EVR, Try_VMR9, Try_VMR7 };

    for (DWORD i = Try_EVR; i <= Try_VMR7; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case Try_EVR:
            m_pVideo = new (std::nothrow) CEVR();
            break;

        case Try_VMR9:
            m_pVideo = new (std::nothrow) CVMR9();
            break;

        case Try_VMR7:
            m_pVideo = new (std::nothrow) CVMR7();
            break;
        }

        if (m_pVideo == NULL)
        {
            hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            break;
        }

        hr = m_pVideo->AddToGraph(m_pGraph, m_hwnd);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            break;
        }

        delete m_pVideo;
        m_pVideo = NULL;
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Each of these initialise in windowless mode for example VMR9

```cpp
HRESULT InitWindowlessVMR9( 
    IBaseFilter *pVMR,              // Pointer to the VMR
    HWND hwnd,                      // Clipping window
    IVMRWindowlessControl9** ppWC   // Receives a pointer to the VMR.
    ) 
{ 

    IVMRFilterConfig9 * pConfig = NULL; 
    IVMRWindowlessControl9 *pWC = NULL;

    // Set the rendering mode.  
    HRESULT hr = pVMR->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pConfig)); 
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pConfig->SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode_Windowless); 
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Query for the windowless control interface.
    hr = pVMR->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pWC));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Set the clipping window.
    hr = pWC->SetVideoClippingWindow(hwnd);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Preserve aspect ratio by letter-boxing
    hr = pWC->SetAspectRatioMode(VMR9ARMode_LetterBox);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Return the IVMRWindowlessControl pointer to the caller.
    *ppWC = pWC;
    (*ppWC)->AddRef();

done:
    SafeRelease(&pConfig);
    SafeRelease(&pWC);
    return hr; 
}
```

And they add the render filter to the graph as follows:

```cpp
HRESULT CVMR9::AddToGraph(IGraphBuilder *pGraph, HWND hwnd)
{
    IBaseFilter *pVMR = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = AddFilterByCLSID(pGraph, CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer9, &pVMR, L"VMR-9");
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Set windowless mode on the VMR. This must be done before the VMR 
        // is connected.
        hr = InitWindowlessVMR9(pVMR, hwnd, &m_pWindowless);
    }
    SafeRelease(&pVMR);
    return hr;
}
```

How can I get the player to display onto a panel?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `IMediaEventEx::SetNotifyWindow` you quoted in your code snippet does not define where the video is displayed. This call is intended to let filter graph manager know where you want to receive notification messages at.

You don't specify what video renderer mode you are using, so I assume it's the simplest (though referred to as "legacy") - [windowed mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/using-windowed-mode). `IVideoWindow::put_Owner` and `IVideoWindow::SetWindowPosition` is how you define where video is presented in windowed mode, `put_Owner` specifically is taking a parent window handle.

#### 2019-06-04 Update

So you are trying to alter [DShowPlayer sample & tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/players/dshowplayer) and the code is using windowless mode.

Stating with Windows Vista the sample would use EVR code path, so I am not sure why you preferred to refer to VMR-9. Nonetheless, they both have "windowless initialization" methods with `HWND` as an argument. This is the window handle where video is embedded. You are supposed to use a visible window handle ([reference](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/players/dshowplayer/video.cpp#L381) for EVR) and also provide valid clipping rectangle ([reference](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/players/dshowplayer/video.cpp#L440)). The sample already does this and you can alter it and use a different window such as your panel in a similar way.

Comment: sorry it is windowless mode that i am using. The microsift code all uses tge same hwnd. I thought this is for the specific window. Do I need to separate the owner handle from the actual display window handle?  Also read in Microsoft on the rendering side it says I need to use cocreate to make the ivideowindow, but doesn't include an example, how do I do this?

Comment: With [windowless mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/using-windowless-mode) you use `IVMRWindowlessControl::SetVideoClippingWindow` or its VMR-9 counterpart, or similar EVR interface. The `HWND` argument there is where you want to embed your window. You can but you don't have to use the same window handle for notifications. I don't understand the part about "cocreate" and you should include more code because it's hard to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I have uploaded source to https://ulozto.net/!DvxVrGHdn0BQ/video-zip so you can see what I have done

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  If you set the windowstate to maximised for the main form.

```cpp
    WindowState = wsMaximized;
```

The handle to the forms is classed as invalid when you try to add the renderer to the graph.

```cpp
        hr = m_pVideo->AddToGraph(m_pGraph, m_hwnd);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            break;
        }
```

I had this line in the constructor for the MainForm and this caused the issue, moving the line to FormActivate fixed the issue.